# What is the domain "safebrowsing-cache.google.com" used for?

Tags: browser

A user on my network has a ton of hits to the address `safebrowsing-cache.google.com`. Is it a proxy to bypass the network filter or is it a Google cache?

Comment: If it's huge all day long, then some browser is not behaving right. Or maybe some portable browser (on a USN stick) does not cache the results, or maybe someone is wiping all cache from disk every time. (I assume that the bad URL cache is *not* cleared when clearing the regular browser cache though.) The initial load of the list of bad URLs might take some time indeed, but I don't know if that's minutes or hours.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Safe Browsing** is a service from Google that helps fighting the spam and phishing sites by blocking them in the browser.

When you go to a site, it's checked by Google. If it's returned as problematic, you get a warning in the browser.

[image]

[Safe Browsing](http://www.google.com/tools/firefox/safebrowsing/index.html) is integrated in Google Chrome and in the Google Toolbar.

Comment: If used by a browser, then it's not used in all browsers. Like obviously Internet Explorer uses its own database for "SmartScreen (See http://www.carbonwind.net/blog/post/2009/09/15/IE8-SmartScreen-Filter-and-TMG-Beta-3-URL-Filtering%28using-Microsoft-Reputation-Service-Beta%29-Whate28099s-inside-SSL%28e2809cquery-traffice2809d%29.aspx) Firefox 3 and later (even without the Google toolbar) uses Google's API though, but makes calls to `http://safebrowsing.clients.google.com/`? (See http://code.google.com/p/google-safe-browsing/wiki/Protocolv2Spec)

Comment: Ah, it seems that the response to calling `http://safebrowsing.clients.google.com` might include instructions to fetch details from `http://safebrowsing-cache.google.com`. Problem solved. The browser should indeed cache these results, so one should not see a browser fetching the full list all the time.

Comment: Thanks , i have no idea why its so huge but caused quite a bit of traffic on the network